# How to get the directory location for file recently modified

Tags: powershell

Suppose we have two directories `C:\username\test1` & `C:\username\test2`. Both directories contain same file `script.ps1`. Now with powershell script I want to search the file `script.ps1` in both directories & want the complete file location of file which is latest modified/created.

I was using below command but it did not give the desired output

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\username" script.ps1 -Recurse  | Where-object {!$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName} | select -last 1
```

Comment: On a side-note, since PSv3 (I think) you don't need to use `$_.PsIscontainer` to distinguish between files and folders.  You can use the `-File` or `-Directory` switches instead.  For example: `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test -File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given directory you can use

```
 Get-ChildItem C:\dir1\dir2 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where {!$_.PsIsContainer}|select Name,DirctoryName, LastWriteTime |Sort LastWriteTime -descending | select -first 1   Name DirctoryName LastWriteTime
```

And if you want it to run for multiple directories, you will have to run a loop on each directory:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\dir\* | Where {$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach-object { Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -ErrorAction Sile   ntlyContinue | Where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | Select Name,DirectoryName, LastWriteTime, Mode | Sort LastWriteTime -descend   ing | select -first 1}
```

It will list files which are last modified for each directories.

**Edit: Search for a file**
You can use following command to search for a file recursively if it is there in multiple directories:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Myfolder -Filter file.whatever -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list all versions of the file found, from newest to oldest:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\UserName" `
              -File `
              -Recurse `
              -Include "Script.ps1" |
    Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Format-Table LastWriteTime, FullName -AutoSize
```

If you only want the most recent one, then replace the `Format-Table` line with:

```
Select-Object -First 1
```